# NoMethodError in Users#new

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I started getting this error:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `has_key?' for nil:NilClass
```

in the process of nearly finishing Hartl's excellent Rails Tutorial. It looks like I must have left out a method, but I have idea where, and am new to debugging in Rails.

Here's the full stack trace:

```
activerecord (3.0.9) lib/active_record/attribute_methods/read.rb:80:in `id'
activerecord (3.0.9) lib/active_record/attribute_methods/primary_key.rb:9:in `to_key'
actionpack (3.0.9) lib/action_controller/record_identifier.rb:82:in `record_key_for_dom_id'
actionpack (3.0.9) lib/action_controller/record_identifier.rb:63:in `dom_id'
actionpack (3.0.9) lib/action_view/helpers/form_helper.rb:331:in `apply_form_for_options!'
actionpack (3.0.9) lib/action_view/helpers/form_helper.rb:313:in `form_for'
app/views/users/new.html.erb:3:in `_app_views_users_new_html_erb___834068491__620833808_0'
actionpack (3.0.9) lib/action_view/template.rb:135:in `send'
actionpack (3.0.9) lib/action_view/template.rb:135:in `render'
activesupport (3.0.9) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:54:in `instrument'
actionpack (3.0.9) lib/action_view/template.rb:127:in `render'
actionpack (3.0.9) lib/action_view/render/rendering.rb:59:in `_render_template'
activesupport (3.0.9) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:52:in `instrument'
activesupport (3.0.9) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:21:in `instrument'
activesupport (3.0.9) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:52:in `instrument'
actionpack (3.0.9) lib/action_view/render/rendering.rb:56:in `_render_template'
actionpack (3.0.9) lib/action_view/render/rendering.rb:26:in `render'
actionpack (3.0.9) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:115:in `_render_template'
actionpack (3.0.9) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:109:in `render_to_body'
actionpack (3.0.9) lib/action_controller/metal/renderers.rb:47:in `render_to_body'
actionpack (3.0.9) lib/action_controller/metal/compatibility.rb:55:in `render_to_body'
actionpack (3.0.9) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:102:in `render_to_string'
actionpack (3.0.9) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:93:in `render'
actionpack (3.0.9) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:17:in `render'
actionpack (3.0.9) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:40:in `render'
activesupport (3.0.9) lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:5:in `ms'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/benchmark.rb:308:in `realtime'
activesupport (3.0.9) lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:5:in `ms'
actionpack (3.0.9) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:40:in `render'
actionpack (3.0.9) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:78:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
activerecord (3.0.9) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:15:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
actionpack (3.0.9) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:39:in `render'
actionpack (3.0.9) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:10:in `default_render'
actionpack (3.0.9) lib/action_controller/metal/mime_responds.rb:261:in `retrieve_response_from_mimes'
actionpack (3.0.9) lib/action_controller/metal/mime_responds.rb:192:in `call'
actionpack (3.0.9) lib/action_controller/metal/mime_responds.rb:192:in `respond_to'
app/controllers/users_controller.rb:29:in `new'
actionpack (3.0.9) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
actionpack (3.0.9) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
actionpack (3.0.9) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:150:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.0.9) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:11:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.0.9) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:18:in `process_action'
activesupport (3.0.9) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:436:in `_run__434435962__process_action__943997142__callbacks'
activesupport (3.0.9) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:410:in `send'
activesupport (3.0.9) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:410:in `_run_process_action_callbacks'
activesupport (3.0.9) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:94:in `send'
activesupport (3.0.9) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:94:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (3.0.9) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:17:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.0.9) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
activesupport (3.0.9) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:52:in `instrument'
activesupport (3.0.9) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:21:in `instrument'
activesupport (3.0.9) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:52:in `instrument'
actionpack (3.0.9) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:29:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.0.9) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:17:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.0.9) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:119:in `process'
actionpack (3.0.9) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:41:in `process'
actionpack (3.0.9) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:138:in `dispatch'
actionpack (3.0.9) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:14:in `dispatch'
actionpack (3.0.9) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:178:in `action'
actionpack (3.0.9) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:62:in `call'
actionpack (3.0.9) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:62:in `dispatch'
actionpack (3.0.9) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:27:in `call'
rack-mount (0.6.14) lib/rack/mount/route_set.rb:148:in `call'
rack-mount (0.6.14) lib/rack/mount/code_generation.rb:93:in `recognize'
rack-mount (0.6.14) lib/rack/mount/code_generation.rb:103:in `optimized_each'
rack-mount (0.6.14) lib/rack/mount/code_generation.rb:92:in `recognize'
rack-mount (0.6.14) lib/rack/mount/route_set.rb:139:in `call'
actionpack (3.0.9) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:493:in `call'
actionpack (3.0.9) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/best_standards_support.rb:17:in `call'
actionpack (3.0.9) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/head.rb:14:in `call'
rack (1.2.3) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:24:in `call'
actionpack (3.0.9) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:21:in `call'
actionpack (3.0.9) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:182:in `call'
actionpack (3.0.9) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/session/abstract_store.rb:149:in `call'
actionpack (3.0.9) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:302:in `call'
activerecord (3.0.9) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:32:in `call'
activerecord (3.0.9) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/query_cache.rb:28:in `cache'
activerecord (3.0.9) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:12:in `cache'
activerecord (3.0.9) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:31:in `call'
activerecord (3.0.9) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:354:in `call'
actionpack (3.0.9) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:46:in `call'
activesupport (3.0.9) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:416:in `_run_call_callbacks'
actionpack (3.0.9) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:44:in `call'
rack (1.2.3) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:107:in `call'
actionpack (3.0.9) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:48:in `call'
actionpack (3.0.9) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:47:in `call'
railties (3.0.9) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:13:in `call'
rack (1.2.3) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
activesupport (3.0.9) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call'
rack (1.2.3) lib/rack/lock.rb:11:in `call'
rack (1.2.3) lib/rack/lock.rb:11:in `synchronize'
rack (1.2.3) lib/rack/lock.rb:11:in `call'
actionpack (3.0.9) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:30:in `call'
railties (3.0.9) lib/rails/application.rb:168:in `call'
railties (3.0.9) lib/rails/application.rb:77:in `send'
railties (3.0.9) lib/rails/application.rb:77:in `method_missing'
railties (3.0.9) lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:14:in `call'
rack (1.2.3) lib/rack/content_length.rb:13:in `call'
rack (1.2.3) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:52:in `service'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/httpserver.rb:104:in `service'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/httpserver.rb:65:in `run'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:173:in `start_thread'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:162:in `start'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:162:in `start_thread'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:95:in `start'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:92:in `each'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:92:in `start'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:23:in `start'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:82:in `start'
rack (1.2.3) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:13:in `run'
rack (1.2.3) lib/rack/server.rb:217:in `start'
railties (3.0.9) lib/rails/commands/server.rb:65:in `start'
railties (3.0.9) lib/rails/commands.rb:30
railties (3.0.9) lib/rails/commands.rb:27:in `tap'
railties (3.0.9) lib/rails/commands.rb:27
script/rails:6:in `require'
script/rails:6
```

I can see that the error is because a User is not getting created during the signin process.
So I went into the console, and just tried to create a User; here's the error stack from that:

```
from script/rails:6irb(main):004:0> user=User.new
NoMethodError: undefined method `has_key?' for nil:NilClass
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.9/lib/active_support/whiny_nil.rb:48:in `method_missing'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.0.9/lib/active_record/base.rb:1512:in `has_attribute?'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.0.9/lib/active_record/base.rb:1672:in `inspect'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.0.9/lib/active_record/base.rb:1671:in `collect'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.0.9/lib/active_record/base.rb:1671:in `inspect'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/irb.rb:310:in `output_value'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/irb.rb:159:in `eval_input'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/irb.rb:271:in `signal_status'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/irb.rb:155:in `eval_input'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/irb.rb:154:in `eval_input'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/irb.rb:71:in `start'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/irb.rb:70:in `catch'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/irb.rb:70:in `start'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.9/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:44:in `start'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.9/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in `start'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.9/lib/rails/commands.rb:23
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
```

I'm using Rails 3.0.9. If anyone can point me in the right direction, sure would appreciate it!

thanks,

### rick

Additional post (9/27/11):

to help my commenters --

yes, I've migrated my database.

where I'm at in the Tutorial: I've basically finished the tutorial, but differed from how it  coded up Users, but using a scaffold instead of the incremental approach that Hartl takes.

here's users/new.html.erb:

```
<h1>New user</h1>

<%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :firstname, "First Name" %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :firstname %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :lastname, "Last Name" %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :lastname %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :username %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :username %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :email %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :email %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :password %><br />
    <%= f.password_field :password %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :password_confirmation, "Confirmation" %><br />
    <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit "Sign up" %>
  </div>
<% end %>


<%= link_to 'Back', users_path %>
```

Where I think is causing my bug is that a user object does not get created by the model, for some reason; and that's why I get the 'nil object' error.

Any help much appreciated!

--rick

Comment: Have you migrated your database?

Comment: could you show your code, and/or where you at in the rails tutorial (which chapter / page / section)

Comment: ^^ Also, can you show line 3 of `users/new.html.erb`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Remember to upvote all useful answers (including answers to other people's questions if you find the answer to be of help to you). Also remember to "check" the answer, if there is one, that best solves your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to Rails and to debugging a Rails program.

Some general debugging tips.

- While the `nil` object does have a number of methods, it is obviously not an ActiveRecord object and thus doesn't have the `has_key?` method.
- So the problem (as you surmised) is that the method that should return an ActiveRecord object is returning nil instead.
- So next is to figure out why. Since you're trying to create the ActiveRecord object it may well be that the object is not passing its validations. Check this by using `valid?` before saving. Or use `save!` instead of `save` The `save!` method will throw an error if the save operation doesn't succeed.
- Learn how to use the logging statement to send log messages to the log file as you debug.
- You can also use the interactive debugger. It can be set up so it'll be invoked when the browser's request reaches a particular line of code in the server. -- The browser will sit with an hour-glass until you "continue" within the debugger.

**Added** Debugging validations

To debug validations, I use a couple of techniques:

- Don't try to use the debugger to follow the execution of the validations--as you've seen, that's a mug's game.
- Do use the debugger to invoke the `save` or `valid?` method on the AR object. You can then inspect the object or use a method to view the error object that is contained within the AR object. The error object will often tell you which validation failed.
- You can also individually comment out validations until you find the one that is giving you a problem.
- You can also use the debugger to examine the attributes of the AR object to see whether the attribute values will pass validation or not.
- Re: when do validations run (as you ask in your comment). Do remember that by default, validations will run on create as well as update calls. If you want an individual validation to only be checked on update (not on create), there are several ways to do that, check the docs for the individual validation.

There's more to say about validations. If you have a specific validation that fails and you don't understand why it is failing, then open a separate question in SO.

**Re: why do validations have to be passed on creation, not just updates** -- that's a feature. It enables you to assure yourself that only valid objects are being created in the db. But you don't have to use it. You can set validations to only be active on Update.

Validations are a powerful, sophisticated part of ActiveRecord. In other words, they can be complicated until they're understood.

Comment: Appreciate the suggestions. I'm trying to use the --debugger server option; but just get dragged down into the swamp of ActiveRecord code, where I get lost.  I now strongly suspect one the validations is returning a nil object (which many are set up to do); but how to tell which one? thx much...

Comment: What is also not apparent to me is why any validations need to be passed for new user object? I thought that should not happen until the object gets saved to the database...

Comment: I bow my head in appreciate of the wisdom in the comments by Larry K...this Rails newbie needs to learn much more about validations in ActiveRecord...I retire to the shadows to study...

Comment: belated thanks Larry; that certainly helped at the time! (sorry I forgot to vote for your answer)

Answer (score 2):

Maybe on your User model you were creating an initialize method that overrode ActiveRecord:Base

```
script/console

class User < ActiveRecord:Base

  def initialize

  end
end

User.new
=> NoMethodError: undefined method `has_key?' for nil:NilClass
```